# Assign Page Template Within A Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, custom-post-type-archives, customization

I have registered a Custom Post Type and created a file called **archive-myCPT.php** and another one for single posts called **single-myCPT.php**.

What I want to do is to create a page where I will show just few posts from my Custom Post Type. Inside my **archive-myCPT.php** I will have a link called let's say "Special Posts" and this link will go to the custom page which will be a little bit different from **archive-myCPT.php**, the only difference is that here I will use a custom query for the posts.

The only way to do this seems to create a page template, but the problem here is that I can not assign a page template to pages within my CPT. I found [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-page-template/) which may help me with the page template support for my Custom Post Type, but is pretty old and I don't know if it's compatible with the latest version of WordPress.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Is this a common / good practice?

Maybe you could recommend something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding a custom query within the template to load posts, the post type of that page doesn't have to be your custom post type. You can create a plain vanilla `page`, create a template for that via `page-your_page_slug.php`, or via a custom template assigned in the templates dropdown, then query for whatever post type you want via `WP_Query`.

EDIT - here's an example using the `single_template` filter. you'll have to change the post type and slug to match yours.

```
function wpa_single_cpt_template( $templates = '' ){
    $single = get_queried_object();

    if( 'myCPT' == $single->post_type
        && 'my-special-slug' == $single->post_name )
        $templates = locate_template( 'my-special-template.php', false );

    return $templates;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpa_single_cpt_template' );
```

adapted from the example on [Template Hierarchy: Filter Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy).

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but what about the PERMALINK structure ? It will look like this : `mywebsite.com/mycustompage` and I want to see it like this `mywebsite.com/myCPT/mycustompage`

Comment: You could add an extra rewrite rule to catch that specific path if you want it to be a child of your cpt slug, or you can add a filter to single template to load it without having to manually choose the template. I can give you code for either of those options as soon as i'm not on my mobile.

Comment: I like the idea to add a filter to a single template to load it without having to manually choose the template. I would love to see an example. Thank you !

Comment: It is possible to call `wp_get_archives` and retrieve the posts within  the custom post type ?

Comment: see edit above. `wp_get_archives` doesn't work with custom types without filtering the query and adding rewrite rules to handle the incoming requests. you can find questions/answers here about how to do that if you search around a bit. custom post types weren't intended for use as date-based posts the way the built in `post` post type is.

Comment: Thank you ! But how about the rewrite rule to make it look like `mywebsite.com/mycpt/mycustompage`, I know how to create a rewrite endpoint but I don't know how to integrate it inside this function.

Comment: if you're using this with the template filter on a single post of your cpt, there's no rewrite rule involved, you'd just name your single post whatever you want the name to be.

Answer (score 1):

You would think that it would be as simple as adding `add_post_type_support( 'cptslug', 'page-attributes' );` to your code, but it isn't. [If you check the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L659) you will see that the template dropdown is restricted to the `page` post type only. There is also [a note in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support#Parameters) and a reference to a [closed Trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12759) on the topic.

You can add that box to your CPT by copying the Core function, making a small edit and adding a new box.

```
function my_cpt_attributes_meta_box($post) {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
    if ( $post_type_object->hierarchical ) {
        $dropdown_args = array(
            'post_type'        => $post->post_type,
            'exclude_tree'     => $post->ID,
            'selected'         => $post->post_parent,
            'name'             => 'parent_id',
            'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'),
            'sort_column'      => 'menu_order, post_title',
            'echo'             => 0,
        );

        $dropdown_args = apply_filters( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', $dropdown_args, $post );
        $pages = wp_dropdown_pages( $dropdown_args );
        if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
?>
<p><strong><?php _e('Parent') ?></strong></p>
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="parent_id"><?php _e('Parent') ?></label>
<?php echo $pages; ?>
<?php
        } // end empty pages check
    } // end hierarchical check.

        $template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_wp_page_template',true);

        ?>
<p><strong><?php _e('Template') ?></strong></p>
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="page_template"><?php _e('Page Template') ?></label><select name="page_template" id="page_template">
<option value='default'><?php _e('Default Template'); ?></option>
<?php page_template_dropdown($template); ?>
</select>

<p><strong><?php _e('Order') ?></strong></p>
<p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="menu_order"><?php _e('Order') ?></label><input name="menu_order" type="text" size="4" id="menu_order" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->menu_order) ?>" /></p>
<p><?php if ( 'page' == $post->post_type ) _e( 'Need help? Use the Help tab in the upper right of your screen.' ); ?></p>
<?php
}
function add_my_cpt_attributes_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box(
    'my_cpt_attributes_meta_box',
    'My Box Name',
    'my_cpt_attributes_meta_box',
    'book',
    'side',
    'core'
  );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_my_cpt_attributes_meta_box' );
```

If you test that code, you will notice that the box appears but the data doesn't save. [Here is why](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2940).

We are going to have to save the data ourselves.

```
function my_save_cpt_template($post_ID,$post) {
  $page_template = (isset($_POST['page_template'])) ? $_POST['page_template'] : false;
  $page_templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
//   var_dump($page_template,$page_templates,'default' != $page_template && ! isset( $page_templates[ $page_template ] )); die;
  if ( 'default' != $page_template && ! isset( $page_templates[ $page_template ] ) ) {
      if ( $wp_error )
          return new WP_Error('invalid_page_template', __('The page template is invalid.'));
      else
          return 0;
  }
  update_post_meta($post_ID, '_wp_page_template',  $page_template);
}
add_action('save_post_cptslug','my_save_cpt_template',1,2);
```

Now it should save but the template doesn't load. [Here is why.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L54) `get_single_template` runs before `get_page_template`, and `get_page_template` is what looks for the specialized templates. So we need to load that template ourselves.

```
add_action(
  'template_include',
  function ($template) {
    global $post;
    if (is_singular() && isset($post->post_type) && 'book' === $post->post_type) {
      $new = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_wp_page_template',true);
      $new = locate_template($new);
      if (!empty($new)) {
        $template = $new;
      }
    }
    return $template;
  }
);
```

Barely tested. Possibly buggy. Caveat emptor. No refunds.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, seems a lot of work to add a custom page within a CPT.

Comment: ... a custom template, yes. That it is this hard is the result of one of the more puzzling decisions in WordPress development.